# inner join select results with a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

How to join select results with another table?

Example: generate 2-column table of aggregate value of each product type

```
SELECT product_type, SUM(value) AS total from table1
WHERE something_something_is_true
GROUP BY product_type;
```

Another table named *table2* has textual descriptions of product types

```
product_type | description | more columns
---------------------------------------
1            | ....................
2            | ....................
```

How to join `description` column to the above selection results so that the resulting table looks something like this?

```
product_type | total | description
---------------------------------
1            | 589   | stationary
2            | 234   | closing
```

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/949e9e/5 try with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery as a table expression:

```
SELECT t1.product_type, total, description
FROM   (SELECT   product_type, SUM(value) AS total
        FROM     table1
        WHERE    something_something_is_true
        GROUP BY product_type) t1
JOIN   table2 t2 ON t1.product_type = t1.product_type
```

Answer (score 1):

Use your query as a derived table and then join your description table to it.

```
select t1.*, t2.description
from (
  SELECT product_type, SUM(value) AS total 
  from table1
  WHERE ...
  GROUP BY product_type
) t1 
  join table2 t2 on t1.product_type = t2.product_type
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
SELECT t1.product_type, SUM(value) AS total,
       MAX(t2.description)
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t2.product_type = t1.product_type
WHERE something_something_is_true
GROUP BY t1.product_type;
```

Comment: @quantum_well . . . If you don't use `max()` the query will have a syntax error.